# How do I return more than one row from an entity to a form in Symfony 3

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to return more than one row from an entity to a form. The form and controller are below.

Form

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ExceptionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('usrid')
            ->add('trcode')
            ->add('cola', NumberType::class,
                ['scale' => 2])
            ->add('colb', NumberType::class,
                ['scale' => 2]
            )
            ->add('colc', NumberType::class,
                ['scale' => 2])
            ->add('cold')
            ->add('fringe', ChoiceType::class,
                array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'No' => 0,
                        'Yes' => 1
                    )
                ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Exception'
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_exception_form_type';
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public function editExceptions(Request $request, Exception $exception)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ExceptionFormType::class, $exception);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $exceptions = $form->getData();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($exceptions);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Exception Added');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->render('exceptions/edit.html.twig', [
            'exceptionForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

This works and renders all the information for one row. Sometimes I will have more than one row that needs rendered in the form. When I look at the debug I get this sql.

```
SELECT 
  t0.usrid AS usrid_1, 
  t0.trcode AS trcode_2, 
  t0.cola AS cola_3, 
  t0.colb AS colb_4, 
  t0.colc AS colc_5, 
  t0.cold AS cold_6, 
  t0.dept AS dept_7, 
  t0.fringe AS fringe_8, 
  t0.seq AS seq_9, 
  t0.id AS id_10 
FROM 
  exception t0 
WHERE 
  t0.usrid = ? 
LIMIT 
  1
```

How do I remove the 'LIMIT 1'?
I;m not sure I am asking the right question, the right way. I've only been using Symfony for about a month. I have scoured google, stackoverflow, and the Symfony docs but can't find what I am looking for or how exactly to ask what I am looking for.

I'm going to try to explain myself better.

```
|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| usrid   | trcode  | cola    | colb   | colc    | cold    | fringe  |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| 25      |   A     | bill    | smith  | 2.00    | 4.00    | yes     |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| 25      |   C     | bill    | smith  | 4.34    | 5.00    | yes     |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| 25      |   F     | bill    | smith  | 1.54    | 2.76    | no      |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| 38      |   A     | bob     | smith  | 2.00    | 4.00    | yes     |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| 56      |   L     | maggie  | smith  | 2.00    | 4.00    | yes     |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| 21      |   G     | mark    | smith  | 2.00    | 4.00    | yes     |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
```

This what my table looks like. On a form I need the to display the first 3 rows, because they are the same usrid. I know how to display the other rows because its pretty straight forward. And this is using only one entity. I'm not joining or using any repositories.

Comment: What do you want to say ? You want get many entities ? And repeat the form n times ?

Comment: Yes. I could have 5 of the same usrid, but different cola,colb,colc,cold, and fringe data.

Comment: Mmm, One form for one Entity, but you want a collection of cola, colb, etc... ? Can you add you entity ? Because I don't relly understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you need one form per row (ExceptionFormType), even if they share their usrid. If you can have (as per your comment) 5 rows with the same usrid, that means you'll need 5 forms, but they can be all embedded in a parent form.

It looks like that entity belongs to another entity where there is only one row per usrid (let's call it user).

So basically, want you want is to create a form which contains forms of your ExceptionFormType.

Have a look at:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html